# How to store instance of class in list?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to use classes to create a leaderboard system that will store movies in order of their ratings

My code:

```
class Leaderboard:
    def __init__(self):
        movies = []

class Movie:
    def __init__(self, name, rating=5):
        self.info = name, rating

spiderman = Movie("Spider-Man",7)
```

How would I store the instance of the class (`spiderman`) into `movies`?

Comment: Whose `self`? You don't have an instance of `Leaderboard` yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of `Leaderboard` first unless you're using it as a static class (in which case, don't use `__init__`):

```
lb = Leaderboard()
spiderman = Movie('Spider-Man', 7)
lb.movies.append(spiderman)
```